# How can I add additional message to flash[:notice]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication.
It always shows a flash message that's saying "You're signed in." right after signed-in transcation.

I have this in `application_controller.rb`

```
if current_user.point_added_at.nil? || !current_user.point_added_at.today?
    plus_point(current_user, 100)
    flash[:notice] = "10 points added for today's sign-in"
    current_user.touch :point_added_at
    current_user.save
end
```

It should show this flash message after first sign-in today.

But it only show the flash message `You're signed in.`

How can I show both (or only "10 points added for today's sign in") after first sign-in of users?

UPDATE:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg.html_safe, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where (in what method) do you have that in your application controller?

Comment: @mbratch I just made a method called `every_time_transaction`. This will be executed everytime the users load a page.

Comment: Which method(s) in your application controller call `every_time_transaction`? The `flash[:notice]` should be in one of your main `erb` files (probably a layout). You'd want to make sure that the `erb` is rendered after you set the message. it's unclear from your info so far whether that's happening.

Comment: okay. let me ask you in other way. Is it possible to add message and make it display just like this? `"You're signed in. 10 points added for today's sign-in"`

Comment: Yes that could be done. Before leaving the `flash` idea (which is a reasonable way to do it), have you located which `erb` displays your `flash` message? You might want to put your new message in the same place (depending).

Comment: @mbratch Yes. It's located in views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: @mbratch I've updated my question. Please check how it's coded

Comment: Where does that new code reside? Can you show its context?

Comment: `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: @mbratch `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: And that code doesn't work? You might need to show more context in your `application.html.erb`. Note you have too many double quotes in your edited example (syntax error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible to show your custom messages.

But, take a look at Devise's Sessions#create action at first

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

The `set_flash_message` line has overwritten your `flash :notice` with the same key. That's why your message can't show.

To solve, two ways:

1. Overwrite this method. You can check Devise wiki about how to do that. Then, in your new code of #create, do something like this

   ```
   unless flash(:notice).present?
     set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
   end
   ```

   This will leave your custom flash if it is there.
2. Show multiple flash messages. This is better but needs some work. At first, give your custom message another key other than `:notice`, say `:custom`, then, in your flash processing helper method, go through each pair of flash, assign correct CSS class to `:custom`.

#### Add

Actually method 2 is not that hard. The simplest code would be like this

```
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I don't want to touch inside of Devise, neither your 2nd suggestion. Isn't there any other way to solve?

Comment: @MKK, you don't need to touch Devise, just write a controller in your app overwriting the specific method. Sooner or later you'll need to that if using Devise. I've added some explanation for method 2.

Comment: Why not do that by simply changing translation? All messages in Devise are available in i18n files

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, it's not Devise's wording not nice or incorrect, it's because this is a totally different message, why mix it with default correct message?